# Как протестировать отправку уведомления пользователю после регистрации?

Tags: laravel, phpunit

Laravel 8.9, в стандартном EventServiceProvider зарегистрирован слушатель, отправляющий уведомление пользователю после регистрации. Как написать тест phpunit на основе этого?

```
protected $listen = [
    Registered::class => [
        SendEmailVerificationNotification::class
    ]
];
```

Пробую следующее, но не срабатывает:

class RegistrationTest extends TestCase
{
use DatabaseMigrations;

```
public function testSendNotificationToUserOnRegistration()
{
    Notification::fake();

    Notification::assertNothingSent();

    $user = User::factory()->make(['email_verified_at' => null]);

    Notification::assertSentTo($user, SendEmailVerificationNotification::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел 2 способа решения. Вместо последней строчки использовать:

1:

```
$user->sendEmailVerificationNotification();

Notification::assertSentTo($user, VerifyEmail::class);
```

2:

```
$event = new Registered($user);
(new SendEmailVerificationNotification())->handle($event);

Notification::assertSentTo($user, VerifyEmail::class);
```